# Same interface multiple client names

Tags: spring-cloud, spring-cloud-netflix, spring-cloud-feign

I'm using feign with spring cloud

I have one micro service that needs to call 3 other micro services, each of these 3 micro services have one end point "/pay" but the implementation is completely different.

This works with feign if I create 3 feign interfaces and call the one I need.

My goal is to create one feign interface and call the service I need (the only thing that changes is the name, since the endpoint is the same for the 3) but I haven't found a way to inject the name in the interface.

This could be done using resttemplate since in runtime I know the service I need to call.

The idea behind this concept is to add more microservices without changing the first microservice.

Comment: Feign supports single level interface inheritance. They is what I would do.

Comment: @spencergibb, you mean creating 3 interfaces extending from a base, changing only the name?

That would work but it would force me to create a new interface everytime I create a new micro service.

I know the microservice I need to call from this one in runtime, there's no way to pass the service name in run-time like in resttemplate?

Comment: Yes, otherwise you could not use @FeignClient and build the proxy yourself.

Comment: I guess I need to use resttemplate then, since this is a requirement :\

Comment: Not using @FeignClient doesn't mean you can't use feign. I've given 2 ways to do it with feign, but rest template works too

Comment: Sure, I'll give it a try, thanks for your help